# How can I used chr(10) in a listagg?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to insert a char(10) into an listagg, but it is not working as expected.

Here is the script that I wrote:

```
select ID, listagg(value , ';')within group (order by ID) as "value"
from DTA 
group by ID


Current Result
ID  |value      |
----|-----------|
1   |aaa;bbb;ccc|
2   |abc        |
3   |abe        |


Desired Result 

ID  |value          
----|------
1   |aaa            
    |bbb                
    |ccc            
----|------
2   |abc            
----|------
3   |abe
```

I tried using this, but it did not work as expected.

```
select ID, listagg(value , chr(10))within group (order by ID) as "value"
from DTA 
group by ID
```

How can I improve on my script?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct. You need a tool that is able to display newline character:

```
WITH DTA AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'A' AS Value FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'B' FROM dual
)
select ID, listagg(value , chr(10))within group (order by ID) as "value"
from DTA 
group by ID;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=230d2a14bb44942ac1180d8663d196e3)**

Output:

```
ID  value
1   A
    B
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below query using PIVOT and its tough to achieve chr(10) using listagg.

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID,  'aaa' value FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID,  'bbb' value FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID,  'ccc' value FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID,  'abc' value FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID,  'abe' value FROM dual )

SELECT CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY DTA_ID
                                    ORDER BY CASE 
                                                  WHEN column_name = 'VALUE' THEN 1
                                             END) = 1
                 THEN DTA_ID
       END "Current ID",
       vals "Result Value"
FROM (SELECT ID DTA_ID,
               VALUE 
        FROM   sample_data)
UNPIVOT (vals FOR column_name IN ("VALUE"))
ORDER BY DTA_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you meet your requirement

```
select ID, listagg(value , || CHR (10)) within group (order by ID) as "value"
```